# Get the double part from string with vbscript

Tags: string, vbscript, get, format, getstring

I want to create a barcode with vbscript that will be decoded from my company's erp (my company devides the nubers with 10000.
The barcode should have this type of look:
99XXXXXXXXXQQQQQQQQPPPPP where: `X` is my barcode, `Q` is quantity, and `P` is the price. With concatenation I have:

`Result = 99 & [sheet$.BARCODE] & right("00000000" & quantity*10000, 8) & right("00000" & VBScript1*10000,5)`

Now VBScript1 has this style, because it is used elsewhere in the program:

`VBScript1 = "PRICE: "& FormatCurrency([sheet$.TIMH SAKOYLAKI]/[sheet$.SAKOYLAKI TWN]*1.3*(Round((40*CDbl(zyg))/CDbl([sheet$.GR/40 TEM]))),2)`

so the output of `VBScript1` is like `Price: $0,40`

Now my question is how to extract from the string the number only and then multiply it by 10000, in order to use it above?

For my example I want Price: `Price: $0,40` to be used as `04000` in barcode.

Comment: it's a string. can't use `Mid()`?

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: Τhank you Marc! I did not think about it!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Split() on $ to get the numerical part of (e.g.)  "Price: $0,40", deal with the decimal comma, pad on the left:

```
>> s = "Price: $0,40"
>> p = CDbl(Replace(Split(s, "$")(1), ",", "."))
>> t = Right(String(5, "0") & p * 10000, 5)
>> WScript.Echo t
>>
04000
>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Marc B said, I tried this and it worked nice and easy :)

```
Result =[...]right("00000" & CDbl((Mid(VBScript1,7,7)))*10000,5)[...]
```